# Why am I getting a Reference error when I try to extend a class from an external class using JS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following code...

```
class BasePage{
    constructor(driver){
        ...
    }
    
}
class Section extends BasePage{
    constructor(driver, parent){
        super(driver);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
export {BasePage, Section}
```

This seems to work, however, when I try to move section into its own folder and file like this...

```
import {BasePage} from "../BasePage";

export class Section extends BasePage{
    constructor(driver, parent){
        super(driver);
    }
}
```

I get an error...

> (node:12480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: BasePage is not defined
>
> at file ... Section.mjs

This doesn't make any sense to me and if I take the extends off and try to instantiate it works fine...

```
export class Section{
    constructor(driver, parent){
        new BasePage(driver); // works fine
    }
}
```

What is going on here? Why am I getting a BasePage not defined?

**Update**

Here is the [whole code](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/2f882b650d6dc83816cbaebf7c85026f)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. I suppose you have circular dependencies that prevent `BasePage` from being accessed at module scope.

Comment: I would like to but I am not sure how to isolate well enough I will work on it. I assume it is related to some sort of circular dependency but not sure why it works in one file then

Comment: There is no circular dependency if both classes are located in one file. Please, publish whole files. If there's circular dependency, these two modules may import each other, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency.

1. `index.mjs` loads `BasePage.mjs`
2. `BasePage.mjs` loads `Other.mjs` before running `export class BasePage {}`
3. `Other.mjs` loads `Section.mjs`
4. `Section.mjs` skips `BasePage.mjs` because it already in-progress from step 2.
5. `Section.mjs` tries to run `export class Section extends BasePage { /* ... */ }`, which throws because `export class BasePage {}` from step 2 hasn't run yet.

You haven't shown why you need to import `Other` inside `BasePage` so it is hard to recommend changes, but essentially you'll want to not do that.

Comment: The reason I am importing other (at least the way I envision it) it that a Base Page is a page made up of other pages. One of these types of pages is of Type section. Navigation is one of these section and is a required part of the base page.

Comment: I ended up solving it in my case by creating changing the imports and having the base page be a prop of Section but I don't particularly like that